# The selected data extension ORACLE is not installed or cannot be loaded

Tags: sql-server, oracle, reporting-services

Our former SSRS base on Windows Server 2010 / SQL Server 2008 R2 / Oracle 11g 64 bit, to present data from Oracle database, it had been worked fine.

After we updated to Windows Server 2012 / SQL Server 2016 / Oracle 12 ODAC 64, then some reports with many parameters, when running show error as:

> Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)

After removing the parameters then can run normally.

All report's dataset edition in Report Builder show error:

> The selected data extension ORACLE is not installed or cannot be loaded.  Verify that the selected data extension is installed on the client for local reports and on the report server for published reports.Microsoft.ReportingServices.Designer.Controls)

I had tried to uninstall oracle client 11 then install ODAC121024_x64, later ODTwithODAC121024 (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html), but all did not work.enter image description here

Now all reports modification are pending, Can expert give me suggestion and idea?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: After install Oracle 12 client full package(http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/database12c-win64-download-2297732.html), all reports (even with many parameter) are worked. But second problem still there.

Comment: Finally, I installed 32 bit Oracle 12 full client in myself computer, then solve it, before my client is version 11.

Comment: Recently, I setup a new computer with windows 10, after installed Oracle 12 client full package, when link oracle data source in SSRS, still got second error, after installing 32 bit ODTwithODAC121024 then worked.